# What do "skreeble", "glurp", and "grindlebloff" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to translate a computer algorithm book to Chinese (from English). But then I came across the following sentences. I know what the author is trying to say, but I have no idea what does "skreeble", "glurp", and "grindlebloff" mean...

> For example, if the original input is a skreeble with n glurps, the input to each recursive call should be a skreeble with strictly less than n glurps. Of course this is impossible if the skreeble has no glurps at all --- You can’t have negative glurps; that would be silly! --- so in that case we must grindlebloff the skreeble using some other method.

The book chapter is available as a pdf [here](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/01-recursion.pdf); you can find the above text on page 23 of the book/page 3 of the pdf file.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @JEL, I think I get what you mean, which makes a lot of sense. However, properly translating it now becomes a challenging task  ┓( ´∀` )┏

Comment: You can use Chinese nonsense words if such things exist. Computer studies course materials used to have examples where companies manufactured 'widgets', a nonsense word representing a product. See also 'foo' and 'bar'.

Comment: These are invented nonsense  words, not established English vocabulary, The facetious exclamation between the dashes effectively confesses the effect their inventor is going for, in selecting and sequencing their vowels and consonants:  silly. (The silliness in "negative glurps" is not the *negative* part.) But readers have to be able to tell which nonsense term is which part of speech. Lewis Carroll's "Jabberwocky" is the best-known example of how this works. How has that been translated into Chinese?

Comment: @BrianDonovan Thank you for letting me know Lewis Carroll's "Jabberwocky". I checked and found, surprisingly, that indeed it has been translated into Chinese! Thought I personally am not satisfied with those translations (yes, there are several versions), at least they hint how to approach such circumstances.

Comment: It may help to know that this sort of thing in computer science is called a metasyntactic variable. The Wikipedia page lists examples in English and other languages, though not Chinese https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable

Comment: There is _Der Jammerwoch_ in German. _»Bewahre doch vor Jammerwoch!
Die Zähne knirschen, Krallen kratzen!
Bewahr' vor Jubjub-Vogel, vor
Frumiösen Banderschntzchen!«_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is that a translation of Jabberwocky? If it is that's seriously ironic since Dodgson was supposed to have been parodying fashionable English translations of German epic verse when he wrote it.

Comment: Keith Lim has a [site with translations of Jabberwocky](http://www76.pair.com/keithlim/jabberwocky/translations/) in a couple of dozen languages, among them French - _«Garde-toi du Jaseroque, mon fils!
La gueule qui mord; la griffe qui prend!
Garde-toi de l'oiseau Jube, évite
Le frumieux Band-à-prend!»_ also Klingon and Yiddish among others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several people have answered in the comments. I'll write an answer.

Computer geeks tend to have a sense of humour that is different from that of normal people. I know because I have worked amongst them!  Where mathematicians would use x, y and other symbols to stand for unspecified objects or quantities, computer folk sometimes use nonsense words. For those who understand the subject, this is considered hilarious.

A justification for using nonsense terms in this case is that we are discussing the abstract concept of recursion and not framing it within any particular programming language or schema. Different languages have different terms for the same thing.

Here is my best guess without reading what goes before.

> *For example, if the original input is a **structure** with n **fields**, the input to each recursive call should be a **structure** with strictly less than n **fields**. Of course this is impossible if the structure has no **fields** at all --- You can’t have  [a] negative [number of] **fields**; that would be silly! --- so in that case we must **process** the structure using some other method.*

Note that the above is a more general definition of recursion than usual. Mostly, when recursing, we reduce a simple count by exactly one each time. This description allows a reduction by any number of **fields** as long as there is always a reduction AND the reduction does not take us below zero.  To grindlebloff *differently* clearly refers to the treatment of the zero or null case at the end of any branch of the recursion. The end of recursion always requires a special treatment.

---

**Note**

A more general version yet would be:

> *For example, if the original input is an **item** with n **attributes**, the input to each recursive call should be an **item** with strictly less than n **attributes**. Of course this is impossible if the **item** has no **attributes** at all --- You can’t have  a negative number of **attributes**; that would be silly! --- so in that case we must **process** the **item** using some other method.*

Comment: Thank you, currently I'm translating it into "For example, if the original input is a problem with n parameters, the input to each recursive call should be a problem with strictly less than n parameters. Of course this is impossible if the problem has no parameters at all --- You can’t have a negative number of parameters; that would be silly! --- so in that case we must solve the problem using some other method." I'll try to come up with a better translation that carries over the sense of humor :P

Comment: Your solution sounds good to me although it might be slightly less general than "item" which could stand for "problem" as well as anything else. Let's see if there are other suggestions.  Frankly I think that the humour serves only to confuse. Especially for those who are not used to computer jargon. When I first learned about recursion, I was lucky enough to read a book that had straightforward language.

Comment: The Jargon File is good introductory reading (and fun IMO): http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/ might be a little dated.